# Can this query or table schema be optimized?

Tags: mysql, optimization

I am running this procedure a few million times, and although each time it takes a few ms, eventually it takes a couple of weeks to run all of them. I was wondering if **anyone could help me optimizing or improving its performance**. Any improvement might save days!

```
CREATE PROCEDURE process_parameters(IN parameter1 VARCHAR(128), IN parameter2 VARCHAR(128), IN combination_type CHAR(1))
BEGIN

        SET @parameter1_id := NULL, @parameter2_id := NULL;
        SET @parameter1_hash := "", @parameter2_hash := "";

        IF parameter1 IS NOT NULL THEN

                SET @parameter_hash := parameter1;
                INSERT IGNORE INTO `collection1` (`parameter`) VALUES (parameter1);
                SET @parameter1_id := (SELECT `id` FROM `collection1` WHERE `parameter` = parameter1);

        END IF;

        IF parameter2 IS NOT NULL THEN

                SET @parameter2_hash := parameter2;
                INSERT IGNORE INTO `collection2` (`parameter`) VALUES (parameter2);
                SET @parameter2_id := (SELECT `id` FROM `collection2` WHERE `parameter` = parameter2);

        END IF;

        SET @hash := MD5(CONCAT(@parameter1_hash, @parameter2_hash));
        INSERT IGNORE INTO `combinations` (`hash`,`type`,`parameter1`,`parameter2`) VALUES (@hash, combination_type, @parameter1_id, @parameter2_id);

END
```

The logic behind of it is: I store unique combinations of `(parameter1, parameter2)` in `combinations`, where `parameter1` or `paramter2` can be `NULL` (but never both at the same time). I store a `type` in `combinations` to know later which `parameter` has value. To ensure that a combination is unique I added an MD5 field (a primary key `(parameter1,parameter2)` will not work because of comparison with `NULL` always returns `NULL`). Each `parameter` has a separate table (`collection1` and `collection2` respectively) to store their unique `id`. There are hundreds/thousands of unique `parameter1` and `parameter2`, but their combinations are highly repeated and are much below the cardinal multiplication.

As an example, `("A", "1")`, `("A", "2")`, `("B", "1")`, `("A", "1")`, `("A", NULL)`, `(NULL, "2")` would yield:

```
`collection1` (`id`, `parameter`)
1, "A"
2, "B"

`collection2` (`id`, `parameter`)
1, "1"
2, "2"

`combinations` (`type`, `parameter1`, `parameter2`)
"P1andP2", 1, 1,
"P1andP2", 1, 2,
"P1andP2", 2, 1,
"P1Only",  1, NULL
"P2Only",  NULL, 2
```

These are the definitions of the tables:

```
DESCRIBE `combinations`;
+-------------+-----------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type                              | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+-----------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| combination | int(11)                           | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| hash        | char(32)                          | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| type        | enum('P1andP2','P1Only','P2Only') | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| parameter1  | int(11)                           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| parameter2  | int(11)                           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+-----------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

DESCRIBE `collection1`; (`collection2` is identical)
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| parameter | varchar(255) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: This looks like a typo:  SET `@parameter_hash := parameter1;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; it is more descriptive than `DESCRIBE`.

**Use LAST_INSERT_ID()**

```
 SET @parameter1_id := (SELECT `id` FROM `collection1`
                          WHERE `parameter` = parameter1);
```

can be replaced by

```
 SELECT @parameter1_id := LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

It will avoid a round trip to the server.

Oops... The OP points out that the id won't be returned if the row is a dup.  This is a workaround that *might* run faster:

```
INSERT INTO `collection1` (`parameter`)
        VALUES (parameter1)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id);
SELECT @parameter1 := LAST_INSERT_ID(id);
```

It's a kludgy trick that is documented somewhere in the documentation.  But; more below...

**Shrink table**

- Do you really need `combination`?  You have another `UNIQUE` key that could be used as the `PRIMARY KEY`.  This might cut in half the time taken for the final `INSERT`.
- This may (or may not) speed things up, but only because the row size shrinks:  Instead of storing the md5 into `CHAR(32)`, store UNHEX(md5) into `BINARY(16)`.

**Batch INSERT**

Can you gather a bunch of these to `INSERT` at once?  If you gather 1000 rows and string them into a single `INSERT` (actually 3 `INSERTs`, since 3 tables are involved), it will run literally 10 times as fast.

Because of needing the ids, it gets more complicated.  You would need to batch things into `collection1` and `collection2`; *then* work on `combinations`.

Since the "combination*" tables are essentially "normalization", see my discussion of how to batch them very efficiently:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table#normalization  It involves 2 statements, one to insert new rows, the other to grab all the ids for the batch.

**COALESCE**

Get rid of `@parameter*_hash` and `@hash` completely.  Change the use of `@hash` call to:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO combinations (...) VALUES
    ( CONCAT(COALESCE(parameter1,''), COALESCE(parameter2, '')),
     ...)
```

Think of it this way...  Each statement takes a non-trivial amount of time.  (This shows up significantly in batching of inserts.)  I'm getting rid of 4 statements at some expense due to adding complexity to one statement.

**Settings**

The most important might be `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2`.

**3 Streams**

Write 3 procedures, each one with the code simplified to the particular `type`.  Combining this with batching should further speed things up.

**Potential issues**

- I think these two will get the same `hash`.  Hence, only one row for these two:

  ```
    ("xyz", NULL)
    (NULL, "xyz")
  ```
- Be aware that `INSERT IGNORE` will burn ids if there is already a row with the given unique key.  Because of this, keep an eye on running out of values with `INT` (only 2 billion).  Changing to `INT UNSIGNED` would up it to 4B, still in 4 bytes.

Comment: Your answer is really useful, with a bit of extra processing I could actually batch the insertions in thousands. Regarding the other tips, I don't use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` because it will only return a value when `INSERT IGNORE` succeeds (when it does insert a row). I realized the burning ids problem, should I change `INSERT IGNORE` for `INSERT IF EXISTS...` or similar? Finally, I use `combination` to use it as an `id` for other tables, instead of identifying that row with the `hash` which is longer and non-numeric (hence, slower to be compared)

Comment: Batching -- Don't go past 1000; there is an issue of "diminishing returns" and possibly even getting slightly slower.

Comment: I added a bunch to the "batch insert" section.  This should address the ids. and still be efficient.  (`IGNORE` is the "if not exists", so "no" to that syntax.)

Comment: Speed of comparison is probably not much of an issue.  However if you don't need or want case folding, use a collation ending in `_bin`.  Anyway, doing the `UNHEX` and `BINARY(16)` maybe even faster than numeric comparisons.

Comment: @Victor - And I had yet another thought -- see "3 Streams".

Comment: I eventually completely removed `hash` and the speed doubled! I will keep the consistency of that table checking the appropriate columns before inserting according to `type`. I removed all the `INSERT IGNORE` for `INSERT ... SELECT ... WHERE NOT EXISTS (...)` and not only sped up the query as well, but also stopped burning `ids`! I didn't dare to change `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit`, I read about it and could lead to inconsistencies. I am still working on the batch `INSERT`. Thanks again!